# how to deal with this minor problem of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

when i am working on below code,python returns

```
for(temp in range(len(history_list))):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

i really can't figure out what cause the error ,if you have any idea please leave a comment,thank you.

```
    with open('history.csv', 'r',newline='') as file:
        history_list = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for(temp in range(len(history_list))):
        if(keyword==history_list[temp][0]):
            #do something
            break
```

Comment: this is not c++, XD you don't need brackets for ```for loops```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: 1) For loop should be within the with block and 2) history_list will be an iterator so you can't index into as you are trying within the for loop i.e. history_list[temp] won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `(` after `for`.

Rewrite as

```
for temp in range(len(history_list)):
    blah blah
```

On a more pythonic note, reconsider writing the loop as:

```
for item in history_list:
    blah blah
```

Comment: Have added a recommendation to make code more pythonic.

Comment: @930727fre - Ideally you should proofread your code for that kind of mistake before posting a question, but you can also delete such questions, which I'd recommend here.

Comment: Use a tool like PyFlakes to syntax check your code. It integrates into most code editors, making it easy to use.